# apply config to group of servers in puppet + hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera, facter

Need some help thinking.

I have 200 servers and have to apply a specific configuration to 100.

The only thing they share in common is the name prefix: they all start with `zmb-`

**hiera.yaml**

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml

:yaml:
  :datadir:

:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/pro/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "nodes/hom/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "%{::os.family}"
  - common

:logger: puppet
```

What should i change in `:hierarchy:` ?

---

puppet version: 4.10.10

---

> We need more information here, to understand what the data is you are
>   sending to your 100 nodes, and why you believe this is a data problem,
>   i.e. a problem to be solved in Hiera rather than in your Puppet
>   manifests. - [Alex Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3787051/alex-harvey)

A very simple example to get things going:

until yesterday all nodes had the same NTP server, `10.1.1.1`
this was set by the class `ntp`, which reads the values from `common`

**common.yaml**

```
---
classes:
    - base
    - ntp

ntp::server: '10.1.1.1'
```

**ntp/init.pp**

```
class ntp ($server) {
    ...
}
```

Now, today, i want to change the IP to `10.1.1.99` for 100 servers, and they all have their hostnames starting with `zmb-`

My question is: how?

Comment: We need more information here, to understand what the data is you are sending to your 100 nodes, and why you believe this is a data problem, i.e. a problem to be solved in Hiera rather than in your Puppet manifests.

Comment: @AlexHarvey edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use a regular expression match (as far as I am aware, and as far as I can tell) in a Hiera hierarchy definition.

You would need to firstly create a custom fact. For example, you could write:

```
Facter.add(:host_code) do
  setcode do
    Facter.value(:hostname).slice(0..2)
  end
end
```

Then you could add a level:

```
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::host_code}" # here
  - "nodes/pro/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "nodes/hom/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "%{::os.family}"
  - common
```

Then create a file `hieradata/nodes/zmb.yaml`.

Of course, I would question that a fact based on the first three letters of the host name is a well-designed fact. What is it about those 100 nodes that causes them to have a hostname `zmb-`? The answer to that question probably gives you the proper basis of your new fact.

Comment: you are 100% right! i should focus on why they are grouped/prefixed with `zmb-`. they probably share more than just the name, and the setting i have to change can be configured somewhere else. i got exactly what i came looking for. thank you for your time.

Comment: Custom fact based on hostname that is defined as a hierarchy level is definitely the quickest/safest path to success here. The suggestion for doing robust `role` definitions and grouping by that instead should definitely be considered too, and it sounds like @RASG recognizes that.